# what is the meaning of "in a nutshell"

Tags: cpu-word

i have came across the sentence  "in a nutshell" while reading a technical book . i want to know the meaning of this sentence(in a nutshell).

Comment: Err...not progamming related. But it means "to sum up briefly."

Comment: http://hubpages.com/hub/What_is_Nutshell

Comment: This is not a programming question. Check out the Cambridge International Dictionary of Idioms for the meaning of "in a nutshell" here: http://dictionaries.cambridge.org/

Comment: I know 'Google It' responses are not tolerated on SO, but Googling for `"in a nutshell"` gives me [this](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+nutshell) as the first result... Afaik SO is meant for programming related questions, it's not a dictionary.

Comment: http://i.ytimg.com/vi/jKMK3XGO27k/0.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's when you summarize something.

[elook.org](http://www.elook.org/dictionary/in-a-nutshell.html) defines it as `adverb` summed up briefly

Answer (score 7):

**In a nutshell** means *in a summarized and very abbreviated form*.

**To be in a nutshell** or **to lie in a nutshell** means *to be within a small compass; to admit of very brief or simple determination or statement*.

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell, "in a nutshell" summarizes something.

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_a_nutshell

Answer (score 2):

> Adv.  1. in a nutshell - summed up briefly; "gave the facts in a nutshell"; "just tell me the story in a nutshell"; "explained the situation in a nutshell"

Taken from: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+nutshell